# How to get volume from mic input

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I'm using the mic input (3.5mm) as a sort of analog to digital converter through the AudioRecord interface. I need to take a sample approximately every 1(worst case) to 3 (best case) milliseconds and measure the volume (relative voltage). Absolute voltage isn't really important as long as I can see the peak.

The problem is I know very little about audio. Can someone recommended how I setup my AudioRecord and buffers, like what size, etc?

Is it possible to observe the amplitude without using a FFT algorithm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this application real-time or are you going to record the waveform, store it and then look at it? For this answer, I have assumed that the processing will be done offline.

You need to take a sample every 1 - 3 milliseconds (worst to best case). If my calculations are not wrong, that would mean a sampling rate of 1000 - 333 Hz respectively. The sampling rate within android is constrained by the minimum sampling rate requirements of your encoder (output format). Looking at the [supported audio/video formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), it does not seem like most of the formats would support a sampling rate of your choice. So, either you could try encoding in the wav format (it might have the sampling rate you need), or record the waveform in whatever format, downsample to your desired frequency range and then analyze.

Also, you can look at this application - [Audalyzer](http://code.google.com/p/moonblink/wiki/Audalyzer) for viewing waveforms.

And yes, you can look at the amplitude without getting an FFT, in fact, not FFT-ing the signal and viewing it just as it was recorded (in the time domain), is perhaps the best way to go.

HTH,
Sriram

Comment: I believe it will be real time. I am making a speedometer that works with a hall effect sensor detecting a magnet on the wheel. Every time the wheel rotates, it sends a voltage pulse through the "microphone" sensor. I don't need to keep any of the audio data, I just need to detect the pulses accurately so I can get a relative time to compare to each other and get the wheel PRM.